# Understanding API transition & inhouse API's

Tags: javascript, json, api, rest

I'm trying to understand API's.

Question1:
I get it that it helps two applications to talk with each other. So if I were to use a third party service in my application, I can do that by using their API. Understood. But why would we need API within a same company ? If suppose XYZ company has a java/ js application and they get the data using the companies internal API. What's the point of having an API when the resource is within the same company. 
Also, should this be a REST or SOAP?

Question2: 
Suppose I have users using my API "x1" which has underlying database "d1" which has a schema "s1". Now, I have completely changed the underlying database & schema to "d2" and "s2" and have a new API "x2" . How can the users still continue to use my API without knowing this transition? How can the transition be done transparently without the users knowing this.

Question3:

Also what does it exactly mean by "rest can be cached? " . Any example ?
There are just two types of API's ? REST & SOAP right?

I was asked these questions by someone & I'm totally got messed up. Can someone explain and clear my confusion?

Comment: "Also, should this be a REST or SOAP?" At the level you're exploring right now, this is like asking "should the documentation be red or blue?" - it's a matter of style, there are definitely pros and cons, and "neither" is also a perfectly reasonable answer.

Answer (score 1):

At its simplest, an API is a set of reusable functions for accomplishing a particular task. So if you write a C program using the standard `fopen` function, you are using the POSIX API, which defines how that function should behave. Crucially, your program doesn't need to know *how* the function is implemented, because the API is an *abstraction* for doing the same task on different systems. The particular implementation will be provided by a library on each target system.

This kind of direct API only works if you are using the same computer, and your program and library are written in languages that can be easily bound together. In some cases, you need to bind more varied resources together, so need a different kind of API. For instance, you might write a script-friendly command-line interface to your library (a text-based API), or use signals and pipes to communicate between two running processes (called IPC, for Inter-Process Communication).

This brings us to *networked APIs*, and in particular Web APIs, which were the main subject of your question. These are just the same as the above, but they use HTTP and related technologies to let processes talk to each other even if they're not on the same host. As you say, this allows an organisation to have a *public* API, but it also allows a system to be scaled onto multiple servers, using multiple programming languages and technologies. The notion of abstraction means that a section of the system provided as an API service can theoretically be competely replaced by a new implementation without any changes to the programs consuming it. If a redesign is needed, it may be possible to provide a wrapper which looks like the old API, and calls into the new one, translating data as required.

There are many ways to build a Web API, but they broadly fall into two categories:

- RPC (Remote Procedure Call) APIs are based around actions, or verbs, with defined parameters, effects, and return values; it as though you are calling a function or procedure on a remote host. SOAP is a particular standard for RPC-style APIs, which defines an "envelope" using XML; it doesn't define much within the envelope, though.
- Resource-oriented APIs focus on nouns rather than verbs, and don't aim to resemble a classic function call. You could consider an RSS feed a simple API of this kind - accessing the URL for the feed causes the server to generate the resource, and present it in a well-defined format for some other program to consume. REST is a formalisation of this idea, using URLs to represent objects, and HTTP requests to represent actions on those objects - GET to retrieve, POST to create, PUT to update, etc. By using HTTP, the idea is to make use of existing techniques used for human-readable resources, such as cached responses, without the user needing to know how the API is written.

Since these APIs are supposed to be language neutral, it is necessary to define how the data is represented; the most common formats are XML and JSON, but there can be others, such as Google's Protocol Buffers.